# Magento 2: get shipment collection by order

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment

I try to add custom action for generate PDF file for merchant (marketplace), like in the backend (*Shipment > Action > PDF Shipments*).

[image]

Try to call function in the backend but it request shipments collection (location: `Magento\Module-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment.php`)

[image]

Right now I have order collection but don't know how to get shipment collection?

Answer (score 8):

You can get shipment collection from order object like this : `$order->getShipmentsCollection();`

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on how to debug it by your own. The **PHP function** called `get_class_methods()` will always be your friend.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_class_methods($order));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This. This right here should be included within every Magento related SO question.